# signing and aligning apk step: No matching files were found with search pattern

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Recently I created a pool agent to automate a build definition for Xamarin Forms (Android) in TFS. Although almost all steps run succeded, signing and aligning apk step throws an error:

[image]

According error, no apk is found in C:\agent_work\1\b\release*.apk, however during building process I went to folder to check it out and I found the file:

[image]

I'm not being able to understand why error. Please need your help! Here build definition for step:

[image]

Comment: Do you use OS X system? Is folder case sensitive? What's the result if you use $(build.binariesdirectory)/release/*.apx?

Comment: I use Windows 10, VS 2015

Comment: Setting path as $(build.binariesdirectory)/release/*.apk according you commented starain-MSFT, not worked, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

Signing process of the APK files  depends on the Java tool called jarsigner. The java compilations that my Xamarin projects do in Visual Studio are done using JDK 8 (Jdk 1.8.0_111), however when reviewing the JDK version with which the Team Services Build Agent compiles, it depends on the variables of Environment that it recognized from the system and registered them in the capabilities when installing the agent in Team Services. %JAVA_HOME% was using the JDK 7 build path, different from the one used by Visual Studio for the same solution:

[image]

Visual Studio solution:

[image]

I actually have two Java versions installed on my PC, and because the SYSTEM CAPABILITIES have been built into Visual Team Services since the agent was first installed, it recognized the path configured in the environment variables of the operating system for %JAVA_HOME%, So it was necessary to adjust the path of this variable, uninstall the agent and reinstall it again. Subsequently the compilation already generated other errors: JAVA_HOME is not set, ANDROID_HOME is not set. This was solved by adding them as predefined variables in Team Services:

[image]

And That's it! Successful building:

[image]

Comment: You can add these variable to the environment variables and restart build agent, then the corresponding capacities will be available in build agent. On the other hand, since the issue has been solved, you can accept it as answer.

Comment: starain-MSFT, restart build agent refers to restart windows service?

Comment: Yes, just restart windows service. If the capacities aren't updated, you can restart machine.